# arrow-body-style error on react useEffect method

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-hooks

Here are my codes using React `useEffect`

```
    const [naked, setNaked] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => setNaked(true);
    }, [props.onWatch]);
```

some reason I am having following eslint error saying :

```
 Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body  arrow-body-style
```

Even with brackets wrapped still having a same issue :

```
    const [naked, setNaked] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
          setNaked(true);
        }
    }, [props.onWatch]);
```

Anyone has good idea to fix this eslint error ?
Please ? Thanks

Comment: Can you show how always-body-style rule is configured in your `.eslintrc` file

Comment: The function you pass to `useEffect` has curly braces, hence the warning based on your ESLint config. Adding curly braces to a different function would just duplicate the error so now you'd have it twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error results depending on how your eslint is configured in your `.eslintrc` file

> If the config is `"arrow-body-style": ["error", "always"]`

It means that you need explicit return and brackets, in which case the solution is

```
const [naked, setNaked] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setNaked(true);
    }
}, [props.onWatch]);
```

> If the config is `"arrow-body-style": ["error", "never"]`

Then you don't have to use `{}` in which case your solution is

```
const [naked, setNaked] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => () => setNaked(true), [props.onWatch]);
```

> If the config is `"arrow-body-style": ["error", "as-needed"]`

In such a case too, you don't require return inside braces and your solution is

```
const [naked, setNaked] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => () => {
      setNaked(true);
}, [props.onWatch]);
```

Please visit the **[following link](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style)** to know more about this rule

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples of correct and incorrect code in the official ESLint Documentation. Further information for this special error can be found here: [arrow-body-style](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style).
In short:

> Arrow functions have two syntactic forms for their function bodies. They may be defined with a block body (denoted by curly braces) `() => { ... }` or with a single expression `() => ...`, whose value is implicitly returned.

Your return has an additional arrow function.
To make your code ESLint conform use the following:

```
const [naked, setNaked] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => () => setNaked(true), [props.onWatch]);
```

I would also suggest that you set up ESLint in the IDE of your choice so that you can have error highlighting or fix your files with a short command.

Comment: Thanks mate! this is great!